# Does MVC6 support Sql Server Dependency Cache

Tags: caching, asp.net-core-mvc, sql-server-2014

Does MVC6 support Sql Server Dependency cache? If yes then what is the process(steps) to implement such functionality.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, MVC6 doesn't per se. ASP.NET Core has distributed cache middleware. Here you can read how to set this up for SQL Server: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/performance/caching/distributed.html#using-a-sql-server-distributed-cache